# Postgresql - Obtener el valor minimo segun la fecha mas antigua

Tags: sql, postgresql, tsql

Tengo estos datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito agruparlos pero el precio_venta es diferente segun fecha_entrada. Necesito los datos agrupados y en precio_venta se muestre el precio de la fecha_entrada mas antigua.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que tengo por el momento.

```
  select

  tb1.id_producto_empresa_cliente as id_producto,
  tb1.nombre_producto_detalle_entrada_empresa_cliente as nombre_producto,
  tb1.precio_venta_producto_detalle_entrada_empresa_cliente as precio_venta,
  min(tb1.precio_venta_producto_detalle_entrada_empresa_cliente) as precio_venta_con_menor_fecha,
  tb2.fecha_entrada_empresa_cliente as fecha_entrada

  from detalle_entradas_empresas_cliente as tb1
  inner join entradas_empresas_cliente as tb2
  on tb1.id_entrada_empresa_cliente = tb2.id_entrada_empresa_cliente
  where tb2.estado_entrada_empresa_cliente = 'ACTIVO'
  group by 
  tb1.id_producto_empresa_cliente,
  tb1.nombre_producto_detalle_entrada_empresa_cliente,
  tb1.precio_venta_producto_detalle_entrada_empresa_cliente
  order by tb1.id_producto_empresa_cliente
```

Comment: La función min() afecta el resultado de select, esta mal implementado, intenta probar sacando el min(), y siempre que puedas muestra los resultados de tu consulta realizada, para ser máx específico con la pregunta,

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En la imagen 1 tengo los datos que obtengo (todos iguales a ecepcion del precio_venta) necesito agruparlos pero en la columna precio_venta necesito que se muestre el valor segun la fecha_entrada mas antigua.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la definición de la tabla `entradas_empresas_cliente`?